# Default value for TextBox in Model

Tags: c#, model

I want to add default value for the model, like this:

```
public class Model1 {
    [DefaultValue("dasdas")]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

**Update**:
Here the code, it isn't working:

```
    readonly IProfilesProvider _profilesProvider = new ProfilesProvider();

    public ChangeSettingsInputModel()
    {
        FirstName = _profilesProvider.GetProfileGroup("Name", "First").ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You need default value only via Attribute?

Comment: No, this can be with the constructor ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd could set default values for your properties in the constructor of your class, which would be applied every time you create a new instance of `Model1`:

```
public class Model1
{
    public Model1()
    {
        Test = "some default value";
    }

    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor:

```
public Model1(){
   Test="DefaultValue";
}
```